# How to change Developer-Name & Company-Name in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

```
//
//  MyViewController.h
//  MyApp
//
//  Created by **Developer-Name** on 11. 12. 27..
//  Copyright (c) 2011 **Company-Name**. All rights reserved.
//
```

I want to change them. How can I change them?

Comment: Take a look at this link here: http://web.archive.org/web/20111201220325/http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/change-company-name-from-within-xcode-on-a-per-project-basis.html

Comment: To change user name go to System preferences -> users and groups -> click on your user, change full name.

Answer (score 8):

You can change //  Created by **Developer-Name** on 11. 12. 27..

**Developer-Name**

go to System preferences -> users and groups -> click on your username

and change  // Copyright (c) 2011 **Company-Name**. All rights reserved.

**Company-Name**

select Project in Navigator -> On Right Side Show the File Inspector -> Change "Organization"

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS 12.x, these options are little bit different. Follow the below steps to change the user name.

1. Go to System Preference > Users & Groups.
2. Click the clock to make changes.
3. Select the User which we need to change.
4. Right click on User > Advanced Options.
5. Change the full name under In Advanced options > Full Name > OK.

[image]